# Fireabse UI sign up without requesting user name

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

Using Firebase UI for sign-in and sign-up, how do I remove the option for a user to sign-up with a first & last name? In other words, only their email and password are required.

According to [this github issue](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/467#event-1431570017), the feature to do so has been implemented.

Firebase provided Kotlin code for sign-in/sign-up:

```
private fun createSignInIntent() {
    // Choose authentication providers
    val providers = arrayListOf(
        AuthUI.IdpConfig.EmailBuilder().build(),
        AuthUI.IdpConfig.GoogleBuilder().build())

    // Create and launch sign-in intent
    startActivityForResult(
        AuthUI.getInstance()
            .createSignInIntentBuilder()
            .setAvailableProviders(providers)
            .setLogo(R.drawable.logo)
            .setTheme(R.style.AppTheme)
            .build(),
        RC_SIGN_IN)
}

override fun onActivityResult(...
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [pull request that implements this feature](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/pull/1108) suggests that you call `setRequireName(false)` on your EmailBuilder object.

```
AuthUI.IdpConfig.EmailBuilder().setRequireName(false).build()
```