# Removing "First & last name" field from FirebaseUI Auth prompt on iOS

Tags: swift, firebase, firebaseui

I've built [FirebaseUI Auth](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-iOS) into my iOS app, but I'd like to remove the Firstname Lastname field from the email authentication prompt. This library has saved quite a lot of time, but my app has no need for this information from the user.

I've reviewed the [documentation](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-iOS/blob/master/Auth/README.md#customizing-firebaseui-for-authentication), and found some [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62721346/remove-first-name-last-name-field-from-firebase-auth-email) [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62135803/fireabse-ui-sign-up-without-requesting-user-name?rq=1) on Stack Overflow about the web version of this library, but I'm having trouble with modifying the fields that are displayed for email authentication in the iOS library. The top answer in that other post suggests that the requireDisplayName property can be modified in that library.

For the iOS library, I tried creating an instance of the email Authorization provider and changing it's requireDisplayName property, but I'm getting the error:
"Cannot assign to property: 'requireDisplayName' is a get-only property".

Am I going about this the wrong way? Or does this functionality just seem to not exist at the moment? What would be a reasonable way to work around this—forking it and removing whatever is making the property read-only?

```
  func presentAuthController() {
    let authUI = FUIAuth.defaultAuthUI()
    // You need to adopt a FUIAuthDelegate protocol to receive callback
    authUI?.delegate = self
    
    let emailAuth = FUIEmailAuth()
    emailAuth.requireDisplayName = false
    
    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
      let providers: [FUIAuthProvider] = [
        emailAuth,
        FUIGoogleAuth(),
        FUIFacebookAuth(),
        FUIOAuth.appleAuthProvider()
      ]
      authUI?.providers = providers
    } else {
      let providers: [FUIAuthProvider] = [
        emailAuth,
        FUIGoogleAuth(),
        FUIFacebookAuth()
      ]
      authUI?.providers = providers
    }
    let fwefwef = FUIEmailAuth()
    // FIXME: Privacy policy
//    authUI?.privacyPolicyURL =
//    authUI?.tosurl
    
    let authViewController = authUI!.authViewController()
    
    
    self.present(authViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
  }
```

[image: The error]
[image: The display as it appears by default]

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I just needed to define the requireDisplayName property when the emailAuth object was being initialized.

```
func presentAuthController() {
    let authUI = FUIAuth.defaultAuthUI()
    // You need to adopt a FUIAuthDelegate protocol to receive callback
    authUI?.delegate = self
    
    let settings = ActionCodeSettings()

    let emailAuth = FUIEmailAuth(
      authAuthUI: authUI!,
      signInMethod: EmailPasswordAuthSignInMethod,
      forceSameDevice: false,
      allowNewEmailAccounts: true,
      requireDisplayName: false,
      actionCodeSetting: settings
    )
    
    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
      let providers: [FUIAuthProvider] = [
        emailAuth,
        FUIGoogleAuth(),
        FUIFacebookAuth(),
        FUIOAuth.appleAuthProvider()
      ]
      authUI?.providers = providers
    } else {
      let providers: [FUIAuthProvider] = [
        emailAuth,
        FUIGoogleAuth(),
        FUIFacebookAuth()
      ]
      authUI?.providers = providers
    }
    
    let authViewController = authUI!.authViewController()
    
    self.present(authViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
  }
```